# Python seaborn plotting from dataframe that was filtered using `pd.Categorical`

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some data from a subset of my dataframe, but it is plotting empty ticks for data that should have been filtered out. I know the issue is that I used `pd.Categorical()`, but I need to. How do I plot only the filtered data (i.e. just `a1` and `a2`) and no extra ticks? Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':['a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a3', 'a3', 'a3'],
        'B': np.random.normal(0, 1, 9)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`:

```
df
Out[1]: 
    A         B
0  a2 -1.076173
1  a2 -2.574480
2  a2  0.863081
3  a1  1.411732
4  a1 -0.937692
5  a1  0.929105
6  a3 -1.071276
7  a3  0.901292
8  a3  0.740417


# Sort A using pd.categorical
df['A'] = pd.Categorical(df['A'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])
df = df.sort_values(by='A')

plotdf = df.loc[df['A']!='a3']
```

`plotdf` should now be a subset of `df`... which it is:

```
plotdf
Out[2]: 
    A         B
3  a1  1.411732
4  a1 -0.937692
5  a1  0.929105
0  a2 -1.076173
1  a2 -2.574480
2  a2  0.863081
```

But when we plot it has retained the filtered-out tick position:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x='A', y='B', data=plotdf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Do I need to re-specify the categories before I plot? Seems a bit odd...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an effect of the categorical type that maintains all of its possible values even if they are not always present (see `print(plotdf['A'].dtype)`).

for example, running `plotdf.groupby('A').size()` returns

```
A
a1    3
a2    3
a3    0
```

with category `a3` showing up despite not being present in the dataframe.

In any case, if you don't want to see this empty space on the plot, you can tell seaborn which categories to plot using the `order=` parameter:

```
sns.barplot(x='A', y='B', data=plotdf, order=['a1', 'a2'])
```

Note that if you want to be generic, you could do `order=plotdf['A'].unique()`